# Object Variable or With Block Variable not set getelementsbyname vba

Tags: html, vba, dom, web-scraping

I am trying to pull the data from websites. So I want to select 3 drop-down values in below URL but i cant change those values.  example i want to select month

```
<select name="fmonth1" id="fmonth1" class="dropdownboxlang" size="1" style="width:60px;">
    <option value="0">MM</option>
    <option value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="2">Feb</option>
    <option value="3">Mar</option>
    <option value="4">Apr</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">Jun</option>
    <option value="7">Jul</option>
    <option value="8">Aug</option>
    <option value="9">Sep</option>
    <option value="10">Oct</option>
    <option value="11">Nov</option>
    <option value="12">Dec</option>

</select>
```

the error i am getting while changing the value in drop-down. I am trying all the possible ways from two days. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
Public Sub bse()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim Dropdown As IHTMLElement
    Dim dropOption As IHTMLElement
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://www.bseindia.com/markets/debt/BhavCopyDebt.aspx?expandable=6"
    End With

    Do
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4 And Not IE.Busy

    Set HTML = IE.Document

HTML.getElementsByName("fmonth1")(0).Value = "1" error line 




    IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css id selector in descendant combination with attribute = value selector

```
#fmonth1 option[value='1']
```

That is:

```
ie.document.querySelector("#fmonth1 option[value='1']")
```

You may need .Click on the end for selected. Can't test that url but also try:

```
ie.document.querySelector("#fmonth1 option[value='1']").Selected = True
```

More generally, if you know an element exists, and your syntax is correct, but you are still getting not set then it may be a timing issue where you need a longer wait (e.g. timed loop) before attempting to access, e.g.

```
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
Dim t As Date, ele As Object
t = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ele = ie.document.querySelector("#fmonth1")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
Loop While ele Is Nothing

If Not ele Is Nothing Then
    ele.Click 'may be needed to expose options
    ie.document.querySelector("#fmonth1 option[value='1']").Selected = True
End If
```

---

If inside of a parent iframe/frame you will need to navigate that first e.g.

```
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("#fmonth1 option[value='1']").Selected = True
```

---

I tested the following now I can access the page:

```
Public Sub MakeSelection()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.bseindia.com/markets/debt/BhavCopyDebt.aspx?expandable=6"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("#fmonth1 option[value='1']").Selected = True

         Stop  '<==Delete me later

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion -  I tried with Css id Selector - the error coming  like this `Object Required`

Comment: I was tried  with `Set a = ie.document.querySelector("#fmonth1") ` and getting same error(object required - runtime error 424) on this line

Comment: See my update for using timed loop. Also, check that the drop down is not inside a parent iframe/frame. Examine the html again and see if there is an iframe/frame tag enclosing this dropdown.

Comment: I checked  - the drop-down inside of  iframe

Comment: I updated answer as I can now access the page and have tested works.