# How to use querySelector to click a button by <a title=""> in VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to use a querySelector().Click to click a button in a browser.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<td tabindex="0" title="Company" class="Smell" role="grid" data-table-header="some header">
    <div class="classroom">
        <div class="first inner classroom">
            <div class="second inner classroom">
                <div class="third inner classroom">

                    <a title="QUERYSELECTOR HERE" class="btn-link" href="/Tosomewhere/here/andthere/111">I'm not trying to grab an inner value because other tables have same inner value</a>

                </div>
                <div class="different sub-classroom">
                    <span class="some span">Mrs. Crobapole</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Here is what I tried:

```
ie.Document.getElementById("Input Simpson").Value = ActiveCell.Value
ie.Document.getElementById("Some button for Simpson").Click
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4

ie.Document.querySelector("[title='QUERYSELECTOR HERE']").Click
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Run-time error '424': Object required
```

The debug highlights this portion of the code

```
ie.Document.querySelector("[title='QUERYSELECTOR HERE']").Click
```

Yes, I did assign an object name and its preceding codes work perfectly fine. But if I click the "debug" button and run the code again, it works strangely.

Comment: Looks ok, you might not be waiting long enough for the page to load. Try adding `and ie.busy = false` to the `Until`

Comment: I added ``and ie.busy = false``. But I am still getting the 424 error.

Comment: By the way, the debug highlights the ``ie.Document.querySelector("[title='QUERYSELECTOR HERE']").Click``

Comment: Now that I look at it, I also think it has to do with page loading because the error message shows before the "loading" javascript icon disappears

Comment: I added ``Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))`` and the error message disappeared.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53984799/6241235) timed loop or [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334183/6241235) points

Answer (score 1):

try catching the object by tag index, on your case index of tag `<a>`, you can loop between the html elements to get the one you need according the attribute on your case `title="QUERYSELECTOR HERE"`
; this code loops between `<a>` tags inside `("td")(0)` and search for the title attribute.

```
Dim MyHtmlTable As Object

MyHtmlTable = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(0)
For i = 0 To MyHtmlTable.All.tags("a").Length - 1
If MyHtmlTable.getElementsByTagName("a")(i).getAttribute("Title") = "QUERYSELECTOR HERE" Then
    MyHtmlTable.getElementsByTagName("a")(i).Click
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = 4
Exit For
End If
Next i
```

hope this helps.