# Why does my code to Scrape Text using VBA works in Debug only

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have written some code to scrape specific dates from Google's patent website.  After reviewing lots of examples I figured out the getElementsByClassName that gets the date I need.  The code below works when I step through in debug mode and generates the desired MsgBox.  But when I run it, it gives me "Run-time error '91':  Object variable or With block variable not set."

I have added delays wherever I thought that might be an issue.  I have also disassociated the code from any interaction with the Excel spreadsheet where I would ultimately put the date, just to make it as simple as possible.  I've also copied the code from the original spreadsheet to a new blank one, but same issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

`````
Sub Get_Date()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim sURL As String
Dim strGrant As Variant

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
sURL = "https://patents.google.com/patent/US6816842B1/en?oq=6816842"

ie.navigate sURL
ie.Visible = False

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4
    DoEvents
Loop

strGrant = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("granted style-scope application-timeline")(0).innerText

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4
    DoEvents
Loop

MsgBox strGrant

ie.Quit

End Sub
    ````
`````

Comment: invariably a timing issue. Use proper page load waits: While IE.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend  for a start and possibly a [timed loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53984799/6241235) to attempt to set the element to a variable then testing if set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely a timing issue as per my comment. That's dealt with in other answers to similar questions. Main things to consider are:

1. Use proper page load waits: `While IE.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend`
2. Possibly a [timed loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53984799/6241235) to attempt to set the element to a variable then testing if set.

Alternatively, a bit of a punt but it seems that all granted dates are the same as publication dates (patent publication date). If this is true then you can use xhr to get the publication date

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub GetDates()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, i As Long, patents()
    patents = Array("US7724240", "US6876312", "US8259073", "US7523862", "US6816842B1")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(patents) To UBound(patents)
            .Open "GET", "https://patents.google.com/patent/" & patents(i) & "/en?oq=" & patents(i), False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            If html.querySelectorAll("[itemprop=publicationDate]").length > 0 Then
                Debug.Print html.querySelector("[itemprop=publicationDate]").DateTime
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks QHarr.  I suspected a timing problem but still don't understand why the delays I had did not work.  Nevertheless, I added a 3 second delay, which seems to have done the trick.  As for your second suggestion, I appreciate the suggestion, though publications and grant dates are not always the same, so not sure this will work for me,  Thanks again.

Comment: could you also provide a couple of examples where dates don't match please?

Comment: I see what you are looking at.  Google now lists the patent publication date as well as the application publication date.  The application is published 18 mos. after filing and is typically different than the grant date.  The patent publication date, on the other hand, would, as you observed, likely always be the same as the grant date.  Because the patent publication and grant date are always the same, we never talk about patent publication, but do talk about application publication, which has significance in certain contexts.

Comment: I think so.  I didn't understand it all, but it looked to be some clever code and those kind of examples help me figure this stuff out.  I have figured out how to scrape most of what I need from these patent pages.  The only thing I'm having trouble with are the inventors.  For example, US7325076B1 lists four inventors.  Any idea how I might collect these names?

Comment: Do you want to open a new question and add your current code?